# installed module in python,still i got error

Tags: python, module, peewee

I tried install peewee module for python using

sudo pip install peewee but when i run my script still i get error

```
sudo pip install peewee
[sudo] password for mounarajan: 
The directory '/home/mounarajan/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mounarajan/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting peewee
  Downloading peewee-2.8.0.tar.gz (470kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 471kB 123kB/s 
Installing collected packages: peewee
  Running setup.py install for peewee ... done
Successfully installed peewee-2.8.0
```

Tried this python Interpreter

```
import peewee
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named peewee
```

Comment: start python in a command line and try to impoirt peewee, if it works, your ide's python bin is a different one

Answer (score 3):

Don't use "sudo" when installing packages.

```
pip install peewee
```

Answer (score -2):

If you accidentally use `sudo` to install some python packages/formulas, and massed up with the permission like me.

> $ brew doctor

can help to diagnostic and give good suggestions. It helped me to fix the problem.

If you are using the virtual environment which is suggested of course. There should be no necessity to use `sudo` which is in most of the case risky.